# GSON how do I test for an key/value pair without throwing a null pointer exception

Tags: android, json, gson, android-json

I have a JsonArray of elements and I want to check each object in the array for a field "video" some items in the array will not have the key, some will have the key and it will be null, I want to only find the elements that have the key and it is not null

```
public void addItems(ArrayList<JsonObject> j) {

    if (j.size() > 0) {


        ArrayList<String> videos = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < j.size(); i++) {

            try {
                JsonElement test = j.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("video");

                if(!test.isJsonNull()){
                    videos.add(test.getAsString());
                }
            }
            catch (JsonParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        if (videos.size() > 0) {
            cloudCache.downloadVideos(videos);
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting null pointer exception on the line

```
 if(!test.isJsonNull()){
    videos.add(test.getAsString());
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JsonElement "test" is null for the object you are tring to find.
As you stated some objects have the video and others don't have.

Just change your code to:

```
if(test!=null && !test.isJsonNull()){
    videos.add(test.getAsString());
}
```

Comment: Oh that was easy, I guess I was thinking the the method isJsonNull was testing if the key existed not the value. thanks.

Comment: You need to understand that the isJsonNull can only be called if the object exists, in your case you don't have an object you just have a " reference" to nothing, so you can tell "nothing" to call a method from something